# JQuery , set attribute for <a> tag

Tags: jquery, attributes

i am use $(expr).attr("hash",value) to set a "hash" attribute for HTML anchor element "a" 
but the Jquery would not do that. but if i change expr to "div", then i can set
"hash" attribute to "div" tag.

is this behavior a xhtml specification? i can set "id" of "a" tag attribute. since id is a built in attribute for html "a" tag.

Comment: It might help if you posted the actual HTML and jQuery that you're using.

Answer (score 14):

> to set a "hash" attribute for HTML anchor element "a"

The <a> element (HTMLLinkElement) already has a DOM Level 0 `hash` property. It is used like window.location.hash to read or set the ‘...#anchor’ part at the end of the URL being referred to by the element's `href`.

Setting `a.hash`, whether directly or through jQuery's `attr()` wrapper, merely sets the anchor name in the link's URL. You *could* deliberately say you want an actual attribute by calling the DOM method `a.setAttribute('hash', value)`, except that this doesn't work in IE6/7 due to a long-standing bug where it confuses attributes and properties.

This is one of the problems with adding custom non-standard attributes to elements, you never know when it's going to clash with an existing name. HTML5 will suggest you limit your custom attributes to names starting with ‘data-’, but in general it's best to find another way of storing data if you can.

Answer (score 6):

Probably your trouble is that there isn't any `hash` attribute for an `<a>` tag. Perhaps you're looking for the `name` attribute, or maybe you want to change the hash in the link `href`, in which case you'll have to parse the link text and replace the hash using regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Another option for setting the hash.  this only works where the expression returns an a element.  This is because hash is a property on the actual a dom element.

```
$(expr).each(function() {
  this.hash = value;
});
```

if your need to test to see whether its an a tag use this

```
$(expr).is('a').each(function() {
  this.hash = value;
});
```

in the case where you actually want to append some custom attribute I would recommend adding the value using the data method

```
$(expr).data('myHash', value);
```